# Access Class Variable

Tags: javascript

I want to access a class variable.but assign data in a constructor.
EX:

```
class Student {
    constructor(data) {
       this.data = data;
       this.extraVariable = "Value"
    }

    getData() {
       return this.data
    }
}

var s = new Student({name: 'Abcd', subject: 'Javascript'});

s.name = 'Xyz';  // i want to access name using s.name not s.data.name

// i want to get updated data by calling this
s.getData() // it return { name: 'Xyz', subject: 'Javascript' }
```

in this class assign data in constructor or setData Method but I want to access those data by directly without this.data.variableName. and I want to get only those data, not other class variables when I called getData method

**NOTE: the member should not fixed like name and subject. if i want to add more members the i don't want tocreate getName and setName methods because members are not fixed**

Comment: but `name` isn't a member of your class. The only member variable in your class is `data` (which is an object that holds a key called `name` in this example)

Comment: just add `this.name = data.name` in your constructor

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can change your constructor to `contructor(data) {this['name']=data['name'];}`

Comment: is there any way to create dynamic member of class because i want to access name directly without data(member)

Comment: @Sphinx thanks for your answer but if i want to get data like in getData method then it return old data. if user update data then i want updated data

Comment: @Deep, one of below answers should be able to meet your requirements.

Comment: @Deep, did one of the updated answers answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

As @Hammerbot has already hinted at, you'll can iterate over the object and apply each property to the current instance:

```js
class Student {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.extraVariable = "Value";
    
    // Assign each property of the object directly to the instance
    Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
      this[key] = data[key];
    });
  }

  getData() {
    return this.data
  }
}

var s = new Student({name: 'Abcd', subject: 'Javascript'});

s.name = 'Xyz';

console.log(s.name);
```

---

**Original answer: creating getters and setters**

You can add getters and setters on the class for `name`. These getters and setters will reference `this.data.name`, but will provide the interaction you are looking for:

```js
class Student {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.extraVariable = "Value"
  }

  getData() {
    return this.data
  }

  get name() {
    return this.data.name;
  }

  set name(name) {
    this.data.name = name;
  }
}

var s = new Student({name: 'Abcd', subject: 'Javascript'});

s.name = 'Xyz';

console.log(s.name);
```

Comment: the member should not fixed like name and subject. if i want to add more members the i don't want tocreate getName and setName methods because members are not fixed

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understand your problem correctly, but as far as i do, id say that you could use getters and setters for this manner.

```js
class Student {
    constructor(data) {
       this.data = data;
       this.extraVariable = "Value"
    }

    get name() {
      return this.data.name
    }
    set name(val) {
     this.data.name = val
    }
    get subject() {
      return this.data.name
    }
    set subject(val) {
     this.data.subject = val
    }

    getData() {
       return this.data
    }
}

var s = new Student({name: 'Abcd', subject: 'Javascript'});

s.name = 'Xyz';
s.name // 'Xyz'
```

Of course the code isn't complete. It would require validation, since the `data` property could be undefined, and you would get an error.

Although its possible to solve the issue you addressed, i would go another way, by defining these internal properties and set them directly.

**EDIT**
So since there is a demand for dynamic getters i would go this way:

```js
...
getProp(propName) {
    return this.data[propName]
}

setProp(propName, value) {
    this.data[propName] = value
}
...
```

Comment: the member should not fixed like name and subject. if i want to add more members the i don't want tocreate getName and setName methods because members are not fixed

Comment: @Deep why don't you create a dynamic getter and setter method then? I'm going to extend my example

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct object-oriented approach.

```js
class Student {
  constructor(configuration) {
    configuration = configuration || {}
    this.name = configuration.name
    this.subject = configuration.subject
    this.extraVariable = "Value"
  }

  setName(name) { this.name = name }
  getName() { return this.name }
  
  setSubject(subject) { this.subject = subject }
  getSubject() { return  this.subject }

  getData() {
    return {
      name: this.getName(),
      subject: this.getSubject()
    }
  }
}

let student = new Student({
  name: 'Abcd',
  subject: 'Javascript'
})

student.setName('Xyz')

console.log(student.getData())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% important! }
```

---

#### Dynamic version

If you want to dynamically create and get fields, you need to create a delegate field to store the data e.g. `this.fields`. See the modified code below.

```js
function extend(originalObject, newData) {
  for (var key in newData) {
    originalObject[key] = newData[key]
  }
}
function isFunction(obj) { return obj && typeof obj === 'function'; }

class Student {
  constructor(configuration) {
    this.fields = {
      extraVariable: "Value"
    }
    extend(this.fields, configuration || {})
  }
  
  setField(field, value) { this.fields[field] = value }
  getField(field) { return this.fields[field] }
  
  removeField(field) {
    if (this.fields.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
      delete this.fields[field];
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  getData() {
    let fields = this.fields;
    return Object.keys(fields).reduce(function(obj, field) {
      if (!isFunction(fields[field])) {
        obj[field] = fields[field]
      }
      return obj
    }, {})
  }
}

let student = new Student({ name: 'Abcd', subject: 'Javascript' })

student.setField('name', 'Xyz') // Update field
student.removeField('subject')  // Remove Field

console.log(student.getData())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% important!
}
```

Comment: the member should not fixed like name and subject. if i want to add more members the i don't want tocreate getName and setName methods because members are not fixed

Comment: @Deep Then you will need to create a delegate field to store those fields. See the second part above.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this but I find it quite hacky and I prefer @KevBot answer:

```
class Student {
    constructor(data) {
        this.authorized = Object.keys(data)
        this.authorized.forEach(key => {
            this[key] = data[key]
        })
        this.extraVariable = "Value"
    }

    getData() {
        let data = {}
        this.authorized.forEach(key => {
            data[key] = this[key]
        })
        return data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got what you're trying to do, the following should do the trick :

```
class Student {
    constructor( data ) {
        this.data = data;
        this.extraVariable = "Value";
    }


    getData() {
        // Updates the modified properties only .
        for( var prop in this) {
            if ( this.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
                if (this.data[prop]) {
                    this.data[prop] = this[prop];
                }
            }
        }

        return this.data;
    }
}
```

**Or** you could separate things like this :

```
class Student {
    constructor( data ) {
        this.data = data;
        this.extraVariable = "Value";
    }

    // Updates the modified properties only .
    updateData() {
        for( var prop in this) {
            if ( this.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
                if (this.data[prop]) {
                    this.data[prop] = this[prop];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    getData() {
        this.updateData();
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

And that's it, you could pass whatever you like :

```
var s = new Student({name: 'Abcd', subject: 'Javascript'});
s.name = 'Xyz';
s.getData();

var s2 = new Student({firstname: 'Abcd', class: 'Computer science'});
s2.firstname = 'Xyz';
s2.getData();
```

Comment: the member should not fixed like name and subject. if i want to add more members the i don't want tocreate getName and setName methods because members are not fixed

Comment: @Deep : Here is you are .